# Applet not getting launched when migrating from JBoss 6 AS to Wildfly 8.2.0 AS

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, wildfly-8

I am new to applet. I am migrating an `EAR` application containing applets from JBoss 6 AS to Wildfly AS 8.2.0. PFB the content of `index.html` which is used to launch java applet as defined in `OBJECT` tag.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" /> 
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-STORE, NO-CACHE, MUST-REVALIDATE" /> 
<meta http-equiv="EXPIRES" content="0" /> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>Installing Tool</h1>
<OBJECT classid="@java.html.object.classid@" width="0" height="0" 
codebase="@jre.url.context@">
<PARAM NAME="code" VALUE="com.test.applet.RedirectApplet.class">
<PARAM NAME="archive" VALUE="@applet.jar.name@">
<PARAM NAME="type" VALUE="application/x-java-applet">
<PARAM NAME="name" VALUE="Launch Tool">
<PARAM NAME="where_to_next" VALUE="../../common/client/test.jnlp">
<PARAM NAME="javaplugin.cache.directory" VALUE="@javaplugin.cache.directory@">
<PARAM NAME="deployment.user.cachedir" VALUE="@deployment.user.cachedir@">
<PARAM NAME="deployment.javaws.cache.dir" VALUE="@deployment.javaws.cache.dir@">
<PARAM NAME="javaws.depl.props.dir" VALUE="@javaws.depl.props.dir@">
You did not install Java.
<p>Please use the <b>Back</b> button to return to the previous page.
</OBJECT>
</body>
</html>
```

I had put debug point in `start()` method of the `RedirectApplet` applet class and started Wildfly AS in `debug` mode.

I noticed that applet class is not getting hit and I don't see any errors in the logs as well. Have anyone encountered such an issue ? Is this problem because of `JAR` files containing JNLP file not accessible by `WAR` files ?  Please help me.

Comment: What's with all the `@` symbols in that HTML?  Is this a file in which those values are resolved at run-time?  If so, post the resolved values, or at least one typical example that fails.

Comment: Can you enable the java console and look if there is an error? Does your applet run in the context of a protected web application?

Comment: yes Lonzak.. applet runs on a protected web application. I had enabled java console and there were no errors found. I am stuck there.